# not able to find where the Java preference is getting stored in Windows

Tags: java, windows, system

I am able to use Java 8 32bit preference api at device level (Windows Server 2012 R2). The value is getting stored and I am **able** to retrieve it as well programmatically, however manually, I am unable to locate it either in Registry or file system. How to locate where is it getting stored?

Answer (score 0):

Check under user settings

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs

If you are running as root, you can also check under:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs

Comment: Nope, checked it, its not there

Comment: I know it is stored in OS level storages, but how to determine the exact location

Comment: Nope, i have checked in both the places, its not seen.
Not seen either in Wow6432Node\JavaSoft